# Want regular expression for following?

Tags: android, html, regex

I have:

```
<description><![CDATA[<div><b>Details:</b> <div class=ExternalClassCDAAC64F989B48B1AE79489DFBF8C27C><div><span style="font-size:8pt;font-weight:700"><font color="#008080" face=Verdana><span style="text-decoration:none"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="http://unipune.ac.in/other_academic_and_service_units/board_students_welfare/pdf/Annual_Essay_Competition_Covering_26-5-12.pdf" target="_blank"><font color="#008080">Letter Regarding Annual Essay Prize Competition</font></a></span></font></span></div></div></div>
<div><b>Expires:</b> 8/14/2012</div>
]]></description>
```

I need a regular expression which will give me only the href contents. I tried with this:

```
String link1 = a.substring(a.indexOf("href=\""), a.indexOf("\""));
```

But its giving me a force close error.

The output that I want is somewhat like this:

```
link = http://unipune.ac.in/other_academic_and_service_units/board_students_welfare/pdf/Annual_Essay_Competition_Covering_26-5-12.pdf
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
String link1 = a.substring(a.indexOf("href=\""), a.indexOf("target=")-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:::: but only if this original string will be in the same format.

```
String[] separated = a.spilt("href=\"");
String[] first = separated[1].spilt("\" target");
String link1 = first[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
\bhref="([^"<>]+)"
```

**Code**

```
try {
    String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\bhref=\"([^\"<>]+)\"", "link=$1");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the replacement text (unescaped $ signs?)
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    // Non-existent backreference used the replacement text
}
```

---

Test it [here](http://regexr.com?312r2).

Hope this helps.

Comment: its not working. It giving output like this: Link=<div><b>Details:</b> <div class=ExternalClassCDAAC64F989B48B1AE79489DFBF8C27C><div><span style="font-size:8pt;font-weight:700"><font color="#008080" face=Verdana><span style="text-decoration:none"><a style="text-decoration:none" link=http://unipune.ac.in/other_academic_and_service_units/board_students_welfare/pdf/Annual_Essay_Competition_Covering_26-5-12.pdf target="_blank"><font color="#008080">Letter Regarding Annual Essay Prize Competition</font></a></span></font></span></div></div></div>

Comment: Have you test it at the link provided?